# User Type for Managed Venues

Tags: foursquare

For Foursquare users that manage venues is there an expected user type that will be returned from the user details call?  Is there a restriction to which types of users can manage venues?

Users of type "chain" obviously manage a bunch of venues but can a "page", "venuePage" or general user also do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users who can manage venues do not have a specific type, and all users who are not "venuePages" can manage venues.

Comment: thats strange. I currently experience, that I need to connect as a page (vanuepage?) in order to manage all four locations connected to that page. As user I only get listed the first location of that chain when, requesting the list of managed venues by this user...